Solana verify Errors
I'm getting below error while trying to verify my program:
cmd:solana-verify verify-from-repo https://github.com/$GITHUB_REPO --program-id $PROGRAMID
Found docker image for Solana version 2.1.0
Unable to find image 'solanafoundation/solana-verifiable-build@sha256............
read: connection reset by peer.
See 'docker run --help'.
Error: Error verifying program. Err(Failed to parse output)
Am I missing something ?
Can someone help with verifying my program. Thank you

This might be a spurious network error. Are you getting it consistently? There's a 2.1.0 image available for use: https://hub.docker.com/r/solanafoundation/solana-verifiable-build/tags

Hi @JonC thank you for your reply.
How can i use this image? I should import it to a specific directory? Can you please provide more details. Thank you for your help

The tool should just download it automatically... do you have docker installed on your machine?
